# win 8.1 with two startup logins. One local and one microsoft account

Tags: windows-8.1

On my win 8 pc when the pc was turned on i disabled the login password and it autogone to the start. After i updated to win 8.1 it first takes me to a login and its not set to me microsoft account but as other user. Thus is fails to login and i have to click below login as a microsoft account and reenter everytime my email and password. In windows in users there is only one user and thats the one i had before. No local account set or something. Same to accounts in control panel. How do i disable this double accounts?

Comment: Set the default account and configure windows to remember the password the process to do this is the same as it was on Windows 7 and 8.0

Comment: You mean set it form user accounts or from local users and groups?

Comment: Have you researched how to set a default account and auto log into that account your comment is not clear

Comment: The thing is that i dont have another account. In win8 i only had my main account which was the administrator aswell. No secondary. So there is no other account to set to default. The admin is the default.  There is no other account in 'User accounts' No other account in 'users and groups' and no other account in the win8.1 settings 'Accounts/other accounts'. But when i startup it fails to login to the local account and i have to switch to microsoft account to login. But i never set up a local account. Want me to upload a video or pictures to show you exactly what i mean?

Comment: I think I might understand.  Since you attached your Microsoft Account you won't be able to log into your local account

Comment: Yea . But i dont want to. Thats the issue. It has 2 logins for me. The one is a local account which loads 1st and it fails to log me in. And then i have to press a key icon below the login to switch to microsoft account. I simply want the local account to be removed so i can auto login to microsoft account

Comment: Have you followed this tutorial?  http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2894-log-user-account-automatically-windows-8-startup.html

Comment: yes i know these steps already. Ill make a video and show you what i mean. Ill send the link to youtube once i upload it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11220/discussion-between-ramhound-and-lantonis)

Comment: Mine was same way. Was showing first name, instead of Microsoft account address. I deleted name and typed in correct Microsoft account address, entered required password 2 times, clicked ok and walla, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem after changing my computer name.

Although I only have one user account xxxxxx@outlook.com it kept asking for the password to a local account when signing in.

Type `netplwiz` in the run dialogue box which should show you your single user account.
Tick the `Users must enter a user name.......` box and click apply.

Untick the box and click apply again.

Make sure the user name displayed in the `Sign in automatically` box is the correct one for the account you want to use. Mine had somehow been changed to my first name.

Add your password twice and click OK.

That sorted things for me and auto login is now working again with my outlook account user.

Comment: That actually worked m8. Thanks alot. Was so simple but yet you dont think a disable and enable will fix it. cheers